# SQLite with Webservices c#

Tags: c#, web-services, sql-server-2008, sqlite, database

I am not sure if this is asked before or not (as I googled it).

Well I have written a web-service that will be hosted with SQLite database.

Many clients would be performing CRUD Operations on it. I planed to use this just for simplicity.

Now I have written my most methods and at this time  I thought that there is no DBMS with that SQLite (I suppose) so there may be conflicts and data inconsistency issues if two or more client applications write to my application.

**or Does SQLite supports managing of operation for multiple connections? or I have to switch to SQL Server 2008**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite "supports managing of operation for multiple connections" in the sense that it won't blow up or cause data corruption.  It is not, however, designed to be as efficient as MS-SQL Server is with a high load of concurrent operations.  So, what it boils down to is how many is "Many clients".  If you are talking about tens of *simultaneous* requests, you will be fine with SQLite.  If you are talking about hundreds of *simultaneous* requests, you will probably need to migrate to MS-SQL Server.  Note that in order for two requests to be simultaneous the two clients must press the 'Submit' button at roughly the same few-millisecond time window. So it takes hundreds of simultaneously connected clients to get dozens of simultaneous requests.

Comment: and in worst case what if there are two requests at same time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes SQLite supports [concurrency and locking](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html)

Comment: Actually my hosting allows one SQL DB and that is occupied.:( so do you think it has heavy downfalls ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. Take a look at [this Sqlite FAQ entry](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5). The longer answer is a bit more complicated... Would you want to use Sqlite in an architecture that is meant to handle heavy transaction loads? Probably not. If you do want to move in that direction I would suggest starting with SQL Server Express. If you need to upgrade to a full-blown SQL Server it won't be an issue at all...

**Sqlite Excerpt:**

**(5) Can multiple applications or multiple instances of the same application access a single database file at the same time?**

> Multiple processes can have the same database open at the same time.
> Multiple processes can be doing a SELECT at the same time. But only
> one process can be making changes to the database at any moment in
> time, however.
>
> SQLite uses reader/writer locks to control access to the database. [...]

Comment: An ASP.net or WCF web service is a single process, each request is a different thread within the same process.

Comment: @BenRobinson: Not necessarily.

Comment: @ben tha tis ok but Read and Write are Issue there.If we have to write some big code there to just handle concurrency then it may be downfall.........